# Exim4 forwarding all emails of domain type to a specific email address

Tags: debian, exim, forwarding

Recently I switched from shared web hosting to DigitalOcean VPS where I have Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) running. In the web hosting I had the option to forward all emails (*@domain.com -- anything as an alias) to be forwarded to my Gmail address.

I have read a few articles on how to accomplish this with Exim, but some of them seem outdated and I am still kinda lost. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Add this router to your `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` file (assuming non-split config), before the `lowuid_aliases` router (assuming you really want such a spam-magnet):

```
catchall:
    driver = redirect
    domains = +local_domains
    data = you@gmail.com
```